# I faced YOLOv5 deep-learning Class Error. Somebody have a good Solution?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, yolov5, labeling

I faced an error in yolov5:

```
AssertionError: Label class 39 exceeds nc=5 in ./data/data.yaml. Possible class labels are 0-4
```

I think the problem with this is that the class of data.yaml is limited to 5 classes instead of 80, in order to download the coco-data set and learn only a specific class.

Does anyone have a way or code to eliminate items other than a specific label (0-4) when learning labeled data?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your some labels have **classId exceed** to 5. Check your label files for every image, some of the **class id will be 39**, fix it. Then it will works fine.

For more details, check this answer too.
[AssertionError: Label class 15 exceeds nc=1 in data/coco128.yaml. Possible class labels are 0-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950508/assertionerror-label-class-15-exceeds-nc-1-in-data-coco128-yaml-possible-class)

Comment: I knew what the problem was, and I asked for a source code to solve it. I finally solved it and thank you for your answer.

Comment: Fine, glad you resolve it.